# Confidence interval that seems conditional on observations. I don't get it.

Tags: probability, proof-explanation, confidence-interval

Is it me or is there something seriously flawed with this question?

Here is their question:

An analyst draws 100 random samples of 16 observations from a normally distributed population with a variance of 1. One sample has a standard deviation of 1.11 and an upper limit of the confidence interval equal to 0.52. Assuming 10 samples do not contain the population mean, the corresponding mean is closest to?

THEIR answer:

First, the standard deviation is known; it is equal to the square root of the variance, or 1. Thus, the population standard deviation should be used to compute the confidence interval, not the sample standard deviation.
**Second, if 10 out of 100 samples do not contain the population mean, this implies a 90% confidence interval**. For a 90% confidence interval, 1.645 is the appropriate reliability factor. Recall the confidence interval is given as follow [....]

And they go on to compute the mean based on the standard equation using the 90% confidence interval to back up a sample mean of X 0.10875

**I don't get it**. What does the fact that 10 samples do not contain the mean have to do with the confidence interval.

To me this sounds like, we flipped a coin 20 times, and 10 times was heads, and saying OK so the 10others must be tails...

Answer (score 1):

Do you not agree that if 100 confidence intervals were constructed at confidence level 90%, about 90 of them would contain the true mean? You’re given that 10 do not contain the true mean. So there you have it: 90% is a reasonable estimate of the confidence level, and then you work backward to get the mean from the right boundary:

$$\bar x=.52 - 1.645\frac 1 {\sqrt {16}}=1.0875$$

Comment: I am given that 10 samples (each of 16 obs) do not contain the mean. I don't see that I am given that 10 randomly drawn means fall outside a confidence interval (even then that wouldn't be enough).

Comment: The (population) mean is "given." It does not change when you draw a confidence interval. So 10 samples (with sample means, which you use to construct confidence intervals) not containing the true population mean means that 90% did.

Comment: @p0001 It assumes that 10 intervals not containing the population mean is the maximum number. They wouldn't say that if there were 20 not containing the population mean. That would be misleading. But I do see what you're saying. So this issue aside, I'm assuming you agree with me?

Comment: Thanks for responding but I think we are still not speaking the same language, my bad perhaps. My point repharsed is this: observing samples from a DGP gives you estimate of the mean and the variance (and as a result the confidence interval) but it does not give you any information about "The LEVEL of confidence". Irrespective of what you samples get you, the level of confidence is a criteria rather than a statistic that can be deduced. Too bad the comment section has to be succinct. Am I making sense?

Comment: Yes, you are right. That's probably why it says "the corresponding mean is closest to?" We could be very far off in our estimate of the confidence level. A confidence level of 80% could even produce 90% of the samples containing the true mean. Think about it this way. All our confidence intervals were using the same confidence level C. 90% of our confidence intervals contained the mean. By definition of confidence level, C% of the confidence intervals will contain the mean. Therefore, we can deduce C could be 90%. However, you are right it is not a parameter to be estimated.